# "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again", when adding new announcement

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I have a team site inside my SharePoint 2013. then i have added an Announcement app to the site, but then i try to add a new announcement i am getting the following error :-
**The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again**

And i have added other apps such as calendars and document management to the same team site, and i am able to add items to these Apps without any problem. so can anyone advice on what is the problem with the announcement App?

Comment: This also should help **[The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue and google suggested me two things:

- Perform an IISReset - No luck!
- Check if have any Free Download Manager installed and associated with your browser? - Turns out I had IDM installed and I uninstalled that And *Voila* its **FIXED**!

Answer (score 3):

I have found this to be directly related to the Search Host Controller Service. This apparently is gobbling up all the memory on the WFE. Once restarted I can now save the form items. I watched it regress from 8gb (max on this server) to about 6.7gb and suddenly this red error went away.  I plan on doubling the memory to 16gb to try to remove the problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

There are already many links related to the errors you are getting. You can probably try these solutions.

- [The server was unable to save the form at this time SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [The server was unable to save the form at this time](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d7845547-e0f1-40de-badd-c66a34c0cfb4/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again)
- [SharePoint 2013: The server was unable to save the form at this time](http://egilhansen.com/2013/08/14/sharepoint-2013-server-was-unable-save-form-time)

And sometimes it's just the memory issue. Your ram usage is very high. Close some applications to free up your ram and it works fine. Check your Ram usage in windows task manager